# Flutter clicking on 1 button should animate rest of the buttons

Tags: dart, flutter

**Main Code**:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: 5,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return MyWidget(index + 1);
  },
),
```

`MyWidget` is a `StatefulWidget` and it's `build()` method is

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FadeTransition(
    opacity: _controller,
    child: RaisedButton(
      child: Text(widget.index.toString()),
      onPressed: () {},
    ),
  );
}
```

**What needs to be done:**

So, as you can see here, I got 5 buttons named `1 2 3 4 5`, what I want to achieve is when I click on any button say `3`, rest of the buttons should animate except `3`. How can I do it?

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**TL;DR :> How to animate other buttons when button 3 is tapped?**

Comment: I know this thing can be done easily without using `ListView` / `MyWidget` but my use case needs to have `MyWidget ` wrapped in `ListView`. I think I need to use `Key` but not sure how they to implement it properly here.

Comment: What kind of animation are you exactly expecting from it?

Comment: Any kind of animation like here `FadeTransition` ƒor ñow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's the most efficient way of doing it but this works, using an `AnimatedWidget` for each ListItem:

```
void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Example")),
        body: AnimatedListView(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AnimatedListView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AnimatedListViewState createState() => _AnimatedListViewState();
}

class _AnimatedListViewState extends State<AnimatedListView>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<double> _animation;

  int _selected;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
    );
    _animation = CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _controller,
      curve: Curves.ease,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 5,
      itemBuilder: _buildListItem,
    );
  }

  Widget _buildListItem(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return AnimatedListItem(
      selected: _selected == index,
      animation: _animation,
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          _selected = index;
        });
        _controller.forward();
      },
    );
  }
}

class AnimatedListItem extends AnimatedWidget {
  final Tween<double> _opacityTween = Tween(begin: 1, end: 0);

  final GestureTapCallback onTap;
  final bool selected;

  AnimatedListItem(
      {Key key,
      @required Animation<double> animation,
      this.onTap,
      this.selected})
      : super(key: key, listenable: animation);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Animation<double> animation = listenable;
    return Opacity(
      opacity: selected ? 1.0 : _opacityTween.evaluate(animation),
      child: ListTile(title: Text("Item"), onTap: onTap),
    );
  }
}
```